# SQL WHERE statement is not working with RIGHT JOIN

Tags: sql

I have the below SQL query, but the problem is that the WHERE statement is not working properly with RIGHT JOIN:

```
   SELECT COUNT(*) no_of_application_by_status, applicationStatusName
    FROM `Application` `a`
    right JOIN `ApplicationStatus` `ass` ON `ass`.`applicationStatusId`=`a`.`applicationStatusId`
    WHERE `applicationTypeId` = '40007' 
    GROUP BY `ass`.`applicationStatusId`
```

[image: Currnet result]

I want to get the `applicationStatusName` where `no_of_application_by_status` = 0

Comment: Move the condition from WHERE to the ON clause!

Comment: Please change your question title it's not clear enough.

Comment: Why not switch to LEFT JOIN? Most people find LEFT JOIN hard enough to understand, and RIGHT JOIN utterly confusing. I.e. `main table left join optional data` is easier to understand than `optional data right join main table`.

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid! 
 
The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the where condition to the on clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) no_of_application_by_status, applicationStatusName
    FROM `Application` `a`
    right JOIN `ApplicationStatus` `ass` ON `ass`.`applicationStatusId`=`a`.`applicationStatusId`
   and `applicationTypeId` = '40007' 
    GROUP BY `ass`.`applicationStatusId`
```

If you do not do it, the joind result will be filtered by the where condition.

Comment: The point is, that condition prohibits null in right joined table column. Not every condition will make right join effectively inner.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Having` you want to fetch group count `= 0` OR if you want to count only the records where `no_of_application_by_status = 0` then use `AND` condition in `WHERE`

`For Group Count = 0`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) no_of_application_by_status, 
    applicationStatusName
FROM Application a
RIGHT JOIN ApplicationStatus ass ON ass.applicationStatusId=a.applicationStatusId
WHERE applicationTypeId = '40007'
HAVING COUNT(*) = 0
GROUP BY ass.applicationStatusId
```

OR count of `no_of_application_by_status = 0`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) no_of_application_by_status, 
    applicationStatusName
FROM Application a
RIGHT JOIN ApplicationStatus ass ON ass.applicationStatusId=a.applicationStatusId
WHERE applicationTypeId = '40007' AND no_of_application_by_status = 0
GROUP BY ass.applicationStatusId
```